# Vue, button click wait for response before continuing

Tags: javascript, vue.js

if my button is clicked for the first time, so a data property is empty, I want to wait for a ajax response before continuing with the button click code.

At the moment when I hit the button I get `wait` and `scroll` straight away so it's not waiting for the response.

```
<template>
    <div class="FinanceSlider">
        <div class="BudgetSlider">
            <div class="ShowPayments">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)"
                   @click="focus"
                   class="btn--secondary"
                   title="See my payments">
                    <span class="ci-spinner spin" v-if="loading"></span>See my payments
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Axios from "axios";

export default {
    data () {
        return {
            quote: null
        }
    },
    methods: {
        focus: async function () {

            // Wait for a quote before scrolling to it.
            if (!this.quote) {
                console.log('wait');
                await this.getQuote();
            }

            // Already has data, scroll to it.
            console.log('scroll')
        },
        getQuote: function() {
            this.loading = true;
            Axios.post('credit-calculator/calculate', {}).then(response => {
                this.loading = false;
                if (response.data) {
                    window.EventBus.$emit('finance-calculator-display', response.data);
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: where you are updating `this.anchor` ?

Comment: @SatyamPathak I have removed that bit as it's not important, shouldn't be hitting the console log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the `callback` as it is the `promise` which is needed to be awaited later. See the following snippet, remove the return from `a.then` at it will behave similarly to your problem

```js
function foo() {
  const a = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => { console.log('2'); res(1)}, 1000)
  })
  
  return a.then(e => {
    console.log('print 3')
  })
}

async function bar() {
 console.log('print 1')
 await foo()
 console.log('print 4')

}

bar()
```

See below I have added a return and it should work

```
methods: {
        focus: async function () {

            // Wait for a quote before scrolling to it.
            if (!this.quote) {
                console.log('wait');
                await this.getQuote();
            }

            // Already has data, scroll to it.
            console.log('scroll')
        },
        getQuote: function() {
            this.loading = true;
            return Axios.post('credit-calculator/calculate', {}).then(response => {
                this.loading = false;
                if (response.data) {
                    window.EventBus.$emit('finance-calculator-display', response.data);
                }
                return true;
            });
        }
    }
```